# how to sudo su during ssh remote command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am writing a bash script to scan multiple linux machines for a line to see if it meets standards for the organization:

```
grep "sulogin" /etc/inittab ~:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin
```

I am doing this using the ssh command like this:

```
ssh -q <<HOSTNAME>> grep "sulogin" /etc/inittab ~:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin
```

the problem is as follows:

1. The box I am on (the Jump Box) cannot sudo into root and then execute ssh. (I know, weird)
2. The box I am on has UserA, which is on all servers.  UserA is on the list of sudoers in which I can execute `sudo su -` manually on each box. (I want to automate this.
3. `/sbin/sulogin` is a root only file. and cannot see the file under any other user.

how do I include `sudo su -` into the ssh command to ssh into the server, then `sudo su -`, then scan the file I need?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, you **shouldn't** `sudo su`. There's no point to use two separate programs where only one will do: `sudo` can do everything `su` can (see the `-i` argument, for example, if you want a login shell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. user has to be part of sudoers.

```
ssh -t user@hostname 'sudo grep "sulogin" /etc/inittab ~:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin'
```